# java replace arraylist of strings

Tags: java, arraylist, replace

I can't seem to figure out how to replace an array list of strings.

```
  ArrayList<String[]> Records
```

So within my for loop i want to replace a record can I keep getting this error.

The method set(int, String[]) in the type ArrayList is not applicable for the arguments (int, String)

```
        for (int i = 0; i < Records.size(); i++) {
            for (int j = 0; j < 2; j++) {
                if (j == 0) {
                    if(!validateRecords(Records.get(i)[j].toString()))
                    {
                        Logging.info("Records could not be parsed " + Records.get(i)[j].toString());
                        Records.set(j, "CouldNotBeParsed");
                    }else
                    {
                        Logging.info(Records.get(i)[j].toString()+ " has been sanitized");
                    }
                }
            }
        }
```

What is the proper way to replace this record using the `Records.set()` ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you are not replacing the entire array, but changing a single entry in an existing array, you need to use a `get()` followed by an array write, instead of a `set()`:

```
if(!validateRecords(Records.get(i)[j].toString())) {
    Logging.info("Records could not be parsed " + Records.get(i)[j]);
    Records.get(i)[j] = "CouldNotBeParsed";
} else {
    Logging.info(Records.get(i)[j] + " has been sanitized");
}
```

Note that your `if (j == 0)` check inside the loop looks highly suspicious, because in effect it makes the loop on `j` entirely useless. You might as well write this:

```
for (int i = 0; i < Records.size(); i++) {
    if(!validateRecords(Records.get(i)[0].toString())) {
        Logging.info("Records could not be parsed " + Records.get(i)[0]);
        Records.get(i)[0] = "CouldNotBeParsed";
    } else {
        Logging.info(Records.get(i)[0] + " has been sanitized");
    }
}
```

Also note that calls of `toString()` are not necessary when you concatenate strings: Java compiler will insert them for you, and also take care of `null` values for you.

Comment: Last question for you.  I was thinking.  Perhaps I should just add another record to the record instead of replacing it. how would that look like.  Records.add((i)[j] = "notParsed")

Comment: @user1158745 That's the problem with using arrays - you cannot add items to them. If you want something to which you could add records, use `ArrayList<ArrayList<String>>`. Then you would write `Records.get(i).add("notParsed")`.

Answer (score 2):

You have an `ArrayList` of `String[]`, and you are trying to give it a `String`. You need to be setting the index of the inner `String[]`, not the outer `ArrayList`.

Do this instead:

```
Records.get(i)[j] = "CouldNotBeParsed";
```

Answer (score 0):

If you have an `ArrayList<String[]>` then it will hold only arrays of `String`. However you have the following line:

```
Records.set(j, "CouldNotBeParsed");
```

`"CouldNotBeParsed"` is a `String`, not a `String[]`. If you really want a `String[]` try this:

```
Records.set(j, new String[]{"CouldNotBeParsed"});
```